# Angular 8, Browser reload page is not working if URl contains dot(.)

Tags: angular

If URL contains dot(.) and we try to reload page with browser reload below error getting:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

We do not want to use (#) in URL.

Thanks

Comment: This is a server config issue with your URL re-writes. Posting some info about what back end server you are using and how it re-writes to your Angular's index.html file will help others point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

are you using **third party login**? maybe you need validate your domain in google api or something like that.

cheers.